# Transfer Google Checkout account to another Google Account

Tags: account-management, google-checkout

As part of the upgrade process for my Google Apps account, I need to transfer my account info to my new Google Account. They have [instructions for many services](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582) but not for Google Checkout.

How can I change the email address or Google Account associated with my Google Checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible.

[From this Google Article](http://checkout.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=186710)

> **Transferring Google Checkout Accounts**
>
> Currently, its not possible to
>   transfer a Google Checkout account to
>   a different account with Google. To
>   take advantage of the benefits of
>   Google Checkout, we strongly recommend
>   that you create only one account so
>   that your information is stored in one
>   convenient place.